# Detecting Enter key for input meant for int type

Tags: c++, input, error-handling, conditional-statements

I am trying to detect and output an error when the user inputs just the enter key when cin prompts for the score. I was thinking
    if(score.size()==0)
    cout<<"not a score";
However this says I need to declare the datatype for score, which is already declared. I feel like there is a simple and elegant solution. I am looking for a beginners solution with a simple condition to check, or any advice to get there.

```
void get_scores(vector<int> &v)
{
    int score, count=1;
    cout<<"Enter scores, enter -1 to stop"<<endl;
    cin>>score;
    while (score!=-1 && count<=100)
    {
        v.push_back(score);
        count++;
        cin>>score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are new to programming.  It's important to learn how to break your problems down into smaller steps.

The first step would be reading a string from the user (instead of an integer).  The second step would be to see if the string is empty.  The third step would be to convert the string to an integer.

You can find good information about each of these three individual steps on this site.  Once you know how to do those three steps, you should be able to put them all together in a program.

I realize this isn't a complete answer but I hope it helps you understand how to approach this.  With enough practice, breaking your problems into smaller pieces like this should become an automatic thing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I am very new so your advice is appreciated. 
So, I understand what you mentioned, however I want to know if there is a way to check if the integer cin was just a whitespace/enter. My instructor (online) told me I could check for the size of the input, ex: if score.size()==0 then output the error. It says error:expression must have class type.

Comment: Try changing `score` from an `int` to a `std::string`.  Then it will have a size and the snippet of code for `score.size()` will work.  However that will break the other parts of your code that treat `score` as an `int`, so you'll have to figure out how to convert strings to integers (search this site).

Comment: The point is that your input method (`int score; cin >> score;`) is not working for you so you need to change it.  It doesn't give you all the features you want because according to you it just returns 0 for empty inputs.  So instead of reading an integer, you could read a string from the user.  You can simply change the type of `score` from `int` to `std::string`.  So now you know how to do the first step in my answer above.  For the second step, you already quoted the code for it: `score.size() == 0`.  For the third step, you should learn how to search Google and search this site.